# In which sense are the Vortex, Labyrinth and Nexus separate worlds?

Tags: the-death-gate-cycle

In the 6th book, *Into the Labyrinth*, Haplo and the mensch of Arianus turn on the Kicksey-Winsey. The robot operating it asks how many worlds were created after the Sundering and accepts "seven" as the correct answer, listing them:

- The Vortex
- The Labyrinth
- The Nexus
- Arianus
- Pryan
- Abarrach
- Chelestra

However, later in the same book, Haplo, Alfred, Marit and Hugh end up in the Vortex and walk into the Labyrinth through a tunnel, showing that Vortex and Labyrinth are parts of the same world. The Final Gate, which connects the Labyrinth to the Nexus, is also shown in several books to be a physical gate -not a Death's Gate.

In which sense are the Vortex, Labyrinth and Nexus separate worlds?

Comment: I also wondered about the '7 worlds' when reading the books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the definition of world being used here is more metaphorical than physical.

We know that after the Sundering, there were five "places" created: the four elemental worlds, plus a fifth "limbo" world, where the rebel Sartan and Patryns were supposed to be rehabilitated and live.

Its interesting to note that the nursery rhyme says this:

> The Sixth Gate is the center, permitting entry: the Vortex

but the **Nexus** is usually described as being found in the center of the Labyrinth, which is a series of concentric circles. To me, this implies that the "center" here isn't talking about being physically in the middle of the world, but rather, that the Vortex world is found "in the middle" of the other four, but that it is sub-divided into 3 logically separate words:

- The Vortex is the entry point into the Labyrinth, and represents essentially a limbo state. People in the Vortex aren't really "in" any world at all; they are in between worlds.
- The Labyrinth is a world of hardship and struggle and danger that makes up the outer portion of this fifth world. It is both physically and metaphysically distinct from the rest of its world -- you can only get into it through the Vortex gate, and only get out of it through the Final Gate, both of which are physical gates but not ones just anyone can open.
- The Nexus is the center of the world, beyond the Final Gate, and is a paradise. Living in the Nexus is as completely opposite the Labyrinth as possible.

The reason the Kicksey-Winsey robot accepted "7" as the answer is likely because the Sartan themselves considered the Labyrinth, Nexus, and Vortex as distinct places; it just so happened that three of them were phyisically connected to each other.

Answer (score 1):

I think the implication is that because there are 7 gates, there must be seven worlds. Although the children's tale in Into the Labyrinth says there are four Worlds, plus these other places.

> The Earth was destroyed.
>   Four worlds were created out of the ruin. Worlds for ourselves and the mensch:
>   Air, Fire, Stone, Water.
>   Four Gates connect each world to the other: Arianus to Pryan to Abarrach to Chelestra.
>   A house of correction was built for our enemies: the Labyrinth.
>   The Labyrinth is connected to the other worlds through the Fifth Gate: the Nexus.
>   The Sixth Gate is the center, permitting entry: the Vortex.
>   And all was accomplished through the Seventh Gate.
>   The end was the beginning.
>   — Weis & Hickman, Into The Labyrinth pg. 9

It could be argued that the Final Gate acts like a Death Gate, as it is required to pass through that gate in order to exit the Labyrinth and enter the Nexus. If someone has been to the Final Gate, they can teleport to it, but I don't believe you can teleport directly to the Nexus from within the Labyrinth.

So the Labyrinth has a two-way gate, which connects to the Nexus, which in turn has a gate which connects to the 4 elemental worlds. The Sixth Gate is in the Vortex, which appears to have a one-way gate into the Labyrinth.

And somewhere, floating between worlds, is a seventh gate.

Comment: I always wondered why there were only 4 gates connection the 4 worlds, and not 12 :)

Comment: @Mike I think they are like Stargates. You can dial a world on them.

Comment: You're right, I am confusing them with the conduits that transferred resources between worlds; those were one-way direct links, I believe, based on the Sartan's plan for when the four worlds were all up and running correctly.